# sum of random variables?

Tags: uniform-distribution

$x\to$ uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$

$y\to$ uniformly distributed on $(0,2)$

$z\to$ uniformly distributed on $(0,4)$

What is the probability that $2x+3y < z$?

I tried to do it geometrically but am not getting the right answer. I believe I have not yet understood the method correctly.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124864/comparing-uniform-random-variables/1125035#1125035)?

Comment: @ Pp No I saw that post but am still not getting the right answer

Comment: What do you want to do? Understand that answer? Check your computation? Check if that answer is correct?

Comment: Understand that answer and how to apply it here when its 2*x